# Issue with android intents:

Tags: android, android-intent

Alright so I have been trying to get all of my separate classes (At present two) into one class using intents. Also been scouring the nets trying to figure out what is wrong and how I can get everything under one roof.

Here is the link to the code:
[My code as of present time.](http://pastebin.stonekeep.com/12171%20%20Code%20as%20of%20present%20time.)
I know all of this works so far since each individual class works on its own. I checked the manifest all is fine on there. Eclipse is showing me no errors yet as soon as I run it, the code biffs.

Its likly something stupid I know but I have been wracked over this for the last few days and I feel like I cant move forward in the code unless I can get this problem solved since I will just end up back at this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not use "main()" methods. All you need to launch your app is to register one of your activities as the main launcher activity. You do this in the manifest.

Then when the users touches the app icon, that activity will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for that but it works for one class / app file, how do I get it to run both? Or rather how do I get it all to run out of the first file: startSpark with out adding other onClickMethods

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a main-method! In your manifest you declare with which Activity your App should start with. This Activity is a class that will extend "Activity". You can override the onCreate activity and start doing stuff in there. I hope I didn't misunderstand you...

This Document might help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html